# How to trigger an event without it happening in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

So, what I want to do is to trigger a setOnMouseClicked event, which I created with lambda expression, without it happening, like a method call in the method start of the main class.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to add an event handler at runtime, or trigger the event and whatever handlers are already on it?

Comment: @Ben N I want to add the event handler and call it like a method in my code.

Comment: @Roland I could do that, but I'm asking this question for learning purpouse and I want to keep my code as small as possible.

Comment: I don't see a purpose for you in creating an artificial event and fire it. Unless you have a good reason to do so. Otherwise just create a method and either invoke it from your main class or from the event handler.

Comment: The thing is, I want the event to work as it should and call the method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify object that will receive the fired event; the target is an object where the event starts and then propagates upwards through a component hierarchy:

```java
MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(
  MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 1, 2, 3, 4, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 5, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null);
target.fireEvent(mouseEvent);
```

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MouseEvent-javafx.event.EventType-double-double-double-double-javafx.scene.input.MouseButton-int-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-javafx.scene.input.PickResult-) for details, but seriously, don't do this.